# Proof Verification, any partially ordered set contains a maximal totally unordered subset (antichain).

Tags: proof-verification, order-theory

I wrote a simple proof and I want to verify it.

I simply argued that the set of all totally unordered subsets forms a partially ordered set, ordered by inclusion. Every chain in this partially ordered set has an upper bound (the entire poset) so we can apply Zorn's lemma to show that our set of totally unordered subsets has a maximum.

Another word for totally unordered subset is "antichain".

Comment: "Totally unordered" is usually called an anti-chain. "The entire poset" is not an anti-chain, so it isn't an element of the new poset. Probably need to assign names to things....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is flawed, since the entire poset need not be an antichain.

Instead you need to show that if $\mathcal C$ is a chain of antichains, then $\bigcup\cal C$ is an antichain as well.

Comment: Do I use this $\bigcup\cal C$ as the upper bound?

Comment: Well, if $C\in\cal C$ is an antichain, what can you say about the relationship between $C$ and $\bigcup\cal C$?

Comment: $C$ would be a subset of the union. I take that as a yes.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted you to see for yourself. :-)